# Airflow - How to save task progress incase of failure?

Tags: python, airflow

I have a limitation using airflow that I cannot control which requires me to use the least amount of tasks as possible in a DAG.

Currently, there are roughly ~25 tasks that need to run sequentially.

The solution proposed is to simply take the commands being executed in those 25 tasks and instead use 1 task and iterate through those commands and execute them.

This solves the first problem but has opened this problem:

These commands can take quite awhile to run and need to be rerunnable incase of a failure. In the proposed solution after encountering a failure, I would have to clear the task and it would restart from the beginning rerunning jobs that were successful, wasting time.

I am looking for design ideas & suggestions on how I can properly store the state of a particular tasks progress and rerun based on that state.

I am only able to use airflow and python to accomplish this. Also, I cannot save files locally. Cloud storage is a possible option but it would need to be a last resort.

One possible solution I have been exploring is using xcom to save the state of the tasks and a separate DAG with a Trigger UI form that would be able to get access to xcom ( like drop down list style ) but I think these ideas do not work together.

I look forward to reading your suggestions to my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

That depends on the implementation of the operator you use and the service it integrates with.

If the service allows tracking of execution then the Airflow operator can try to reattach to the executed job. In that case if for some reason the task from Airflow side is getting terminated (for example worker is restarted) when it respawn the task will retry and reattach to the running remote job.

The logic of reattach needs to be implemented in the operator. The logic contains a check of the tracked job status and if met the defined logic the task will continue monitor this job rather than creating a new one.

Some operators already have this functionality, for example:

[KubernetesPodOperator](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/6412b06a7b35a0743656dd3b2160f390f40108c2/airflow/providers/cncf/kubernetes/operators/pod.py#L139-L140):

```
KubernetesPodOperator(..., reattach_on_restart=True)
```

[EcsRunTaskOperator](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/c75a1059355df6e1edc42f77947150b4a4c5d51a/airflow/providers/amazon/aws/operators/ecs.py#L400-L403):

```
EcsRunTaskOperator(..., reattach=True)
```

[BigQueryToGCSOperator](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/2d0d78b20a1582e02251d2ff1c4a24827c194ee7/airflow/providers/google/cloud/transfers/bigquery_to_gcs.py#L84-L85):

```
BigQueryToGCSOperator(..., reattach_states={"PENDING"})
```

If the operator you use doesn't have this functionality you can implement it. The above example code can be used as reference for the implementation - note that the implementation vary between different services according to the API capabilities the service expose.